# Change class attribute dynamically inline with tailwind

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, inline, svelte, string-literals

How do I pass in a dynamic value using a string literal with tailwind inline css?

For example I want to change the width dynamically, and not use tailwinds premade w-1, w-2, etc...

```html
<div
  class="p-1 border-2 width: {createTimeBlock(
    show.startTime,
    show.endTime,
  )}px">
  {show.startTime} to {show.endTime}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `w-[{...}px]`, but Tailwind relies to classes to be statically known, so this will probably not work.

The easiest thing would probably be to just use [`style:width="..."`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property) or `style="width: ..."`. Though this will have high precedence due to being an inline style.

Alternatively, you can create a local component class that reads width from a custom property, then set the property using CSS attribute syntax, e.g. `style:--width="..."` [for elements](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property) or `--width="..."` [for components](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props), or via the style attribute as `style="--width: ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around, if `createTimeBlock` will return a fixed set of values ( say `[v1, v2, .... vN]` ) for which there is a fixed set of width values to set ( assuming `creatTimeBlock` returns only increments of 15mins for example ), you can do this.

```html
<script>
$timeblock = createTimeBlock( startTime, endTime );
</script>

<div
 class="p-1 border-2..."
 class:width_v1={timeblock === v1}
 class:width_v2={timeblock === v2}
 ...
 class:width_vN={timeblock === vN}
>
 {startTime} to {endTime}
</div>

<style>
 .width_v1{ 
   width: v1_width_px; 
 }
 .width_v2{ width: v2_width_px; }
 ....
 .width_vN{ width: vN_width_px; }
</style>
```

Note, the actual `.width_v1` class can actually be a native width class to tailwind like say `w-8`.
Hope this helps.